# How to loop through a list and print the outputs

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm really new to Excel VBA but recently need to come up with a solution to have excel iterate through a list and print the output.

Here on tab "Sheet2" is the item master. Each of the items is designated an Item Code.

[image: sheet2]

On "Sheet1" I have a formula that finds the Unit Price and Starting Level and calculates the Total On Hand Liabilities.

[image: Sheet1]

I'd like to have Excel populate in cell Sheet1!A2 with each of the values in range Sheet2!A1:A, do the calculations, and paste all each of the outputs in a new sheet, as shown below.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Add the Developer Tab to Excel and record a Macro manually. That will show you all the commands, then wrap that code in a For Loop and swap cell addresses/references with the Integer Iterator variable, eg  `Range("C" & i).Value`

Comment: Why use VBA for that? Do you need the repeated labels in rows 1, 4, 7, etc? Just use formulas. That's what Excel does.

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic macro to do this, maybe you could tweak it to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim switch As Boolean
    
    switch = False
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
        
'so that for the first iteration it will not offset, assuming you start off with blank wksht
        If switch = True Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
        End If

        ActiveCell.Value = "Item Number"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Description"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "On Hand Liability"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = rng.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2) * rng.Offset(0, 3)
        switch = True
    Next rng


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you use the Microsoft VBA language reference to look up loops. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement

Here is an example which will produce your output:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateSheet1()

    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Range
    Dim SourceRows  As Long
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    SourceRows = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TargetRow = 1
    For Each SourceRow In SourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & SourceRows)
        TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 1) = Array("Item Number", "Description", "On Hand Liability")
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        
        SourceRow.Cells(1, 1).Copy TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 1)
        TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 2) = "=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A" & TargetRow & ",Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)"
        TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 3) = "=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A" & TargetRow & ",Sheet2!A:D,3,FALSE) * VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A" & TargetRow & ",Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE)"
        TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 3).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 2
    Next

End Sub
```